# ASP.NET Core Web API - Parameter binding does not work when member of a class is list of Interface

Tags: class, asp.net-core, interface, asp.net-core-webapi

```
public async Task<IActionResult> AddProjectDetail(ProjectViewModel project)
{
//
}    

public class ProjectViewModel : IProjectViewModel
        {
           public string Id { get; set; }
           public IKeyValue UOPSegment { get; set; } = new KeyValue();
           public IList<IProjectGateAssocViewModel> ProjectGates { get; set; } //Data is not getting binded here
        }

    public interface IProjectViewModel : IBaseDBModel
        {
            string Id { get; set; }
            IKeyValue UOPSegment { get; set; }
            IList<IProjectGateAssocViewModel> ProjectGates { get; set; }
        }

    public interface IProjectGateAssocViewModel 
        {
            string GateCode { get; set; }
            string GateDate { get; set; }
            string ProjectId { get; set; }
        }
    
    public class ProjectGateAssocViewModel : IProjectGateAssocViewModel
        {
            public string GateCode { get; set; }
            public string GateDate { get; set; }
            public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        }
```

// public IList ProjectGates { get; set; }

Here data is not getting bind.
When I try to call API I am getting below error:

> {   "projectFiles[0].contentType": [
> "The input was not valid."   ] }

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are expecting that ASP.NET Core binding is capable of instantiating interface object. Which is not possible. Or you are expecting ASP.NET Core binding is capable of guessing which type you'd like to instantiate for given interface. Which is possible, but I am afraid it is something no one ever considered as valid binding scenario.

To understand the problem with binding you need to know how it is working. Binding is capable of binding simple types, complex types with public parameterless constructor and writable properties, collections and dictionaries.

**Simple types** ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#simple-types))

The simple types that the model binder can convert source strings into include the following:

`Boolean`, `Byte`, `SByte`, `Char`, `DateTime`, `DateTimeOffset`, `Decimal`, `Double`, `Enum`, `Guid`, `Int16`, `Int32`, `Int64`, `Single`, `TimeSpan`, `UInt16`, `UInt32`, `UInt64`, `Uri`, `Version`

**Complex types** ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#complex-types))

A complex type must have a public default constructor and public writable properties to bind. When model binding occurs, the class is instantiated using the public default constructor.

For each property of the complex type, model binding looks through the sources for the name pattern prefix.property_name. If nothing is found, it looks for just property_name without the prefix.

For binding to a parameter, the prefix is the parameter name. For binding to a PageModel public property, the prefix is the public property name. Some attributes have a Prefix property that lets you override the default usage of parameter or property name.

**Collections** ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#collections))

For targets that are collections of simple types, model binding looks for matches to parameter_name or property_name. If no match is found, it looks for one of the supported formats without the prefix.

**Dictionaries** ([Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1#dictionaries))

For Dictionary targets, model binding looks for matches to parameter_name or property_name. If no match is found, it looks for one of the supported formats without the prefix.

**Extras** (not docummented)

So far ASP.NET Core binding is that nice that is capable of binding to `IEnumerable<T>` or `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` for you.

**Option 1**

Avoid binding to interfaces. You'll save yourself lot of struggles.

```
public class ProjectViewModel : IProjectViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public IList<ProjectGateAssocViewModel> ProjectGates { get; set; } //Data are getting binded here now
}

public interface IProjectViewModel
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    IList<ProjectGateAssocViewModel> ProjectGates { get; set; }
}
public interface IProjectGateAssocViewModel
{
    string GateCode { get; set; }
    string GateDate { get; set; }
    string ProjectId { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectGateAssocViewModel : IProjectGateAssocViewModel
{
    public string GateCode { get; set; }
    public string GateDate { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }

}
```

**Option 2**

Implement custom binder(s), custom type converter(s) or custom formatter(s) as you need to instantiate objects first.

It is hard to say which method you should use as it depends on requests you are making and how those are processed.